# Add key to nested hash while iterating over a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Say I have a hash like:

```
myhash = {'key1': {'innerkey1': 'innervalue1', ...}, ...}
```

I would like to iterate over this hash and add a key-value pair to the inner hash. The above example becomes:

```
myhash = {'key1': {'innerkey1': 'innervalue1', 'addedkey': 'addedvalue', ...}, ...}
```

I tried with `myhash.each do |k, v|`, but changing `v` in the block affects the hash only within the block's scope. It works by doing `myhash[k]['addedkey'] = 'addedvalue'` inside the block, but I would like to modify the inner hash in place, not use `myhash` to do this.

How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: `addedkey` is nested within `myhash` you have to start at the upper level.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't quite understood what you've meant.

Comment: You're trying to access the inner hash object without going through the outer hash object, right?

Comment: No, I am doing an `each` over `myhash`, and in that block I am trying to add to the current value.

Comment: I'm really not sure I'm following here.  Is this what you're doing? https://gist.github.com/allcentury/7d91592e75ffabbe71a2

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve. But somehow after exiting the block, `myhash` is not changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68283/discussion-between-anthony-and-andrei-horak).

Answer (score 4):

Use [Hash `merge!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) method:

```
myhash = { k1: { innerk1: 'innerv1' },  k2: { innerk2: 'innerv2' } }

myhash.each do |key, value|
  value.merge!({ addedk: 'addedv' })
end

p myhash

# {:k1=>{:innerk1=>"innerv1", :addedk=>"addedv"}, :k2=>{:innerk2=>"innerv2", :addedk=>"addedv"}}
```

Comment: this is 3x slower than just doing assignment, ie `value['addkey'] = 'newvalue'`

Comment: But why isn't my changed value reflected upon exiting the block where I have made the change?

Comment: @AndreiHorak what do you mean your "change isn't reflected"? Are you sure you are using the bang(`!`) version of `#merge`. If you use `#merge` nothing will change but using `#merge!` will mutate the object in place. But As Anthony stated assignment is faster and will also reflect the change

Comment: I was replying to Anthony's comment. If assignment works in the block, then it must be my mistake somewhere. Anthony, you can submit your answer then :)